# pandas resample on business days

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for a way to generate data for every second business day from daily data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
index = pd.date_range("20210201", "20210501", freq="B")
data = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.arange(0, len(index))}, index=index)
```

If I run

```
data.resample("2D").last()
```

I get

```
            a
2021-02-01  1.0
2021-02-03  3.0
2021-02-05  4.0
2021-02-07  5.0
2021-02-09  7.0
2021-02-11  9.0
2021-02-13  NaN
2021-02-15  11.0
```

I'd like to ignore weekends and only use weekdays, is there any way to do it with resample?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I've found a solution

```
data.resample(pd.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay(2)).last()
```